# Most resource intensive assembly instructions?

Tags: attacks, appsec, ddos, denial-of-service

Assuming I want to overload a server which is running some kind of web-app or gaming server, what is the best way for me to figure out which usage of legitimate features on the web-app or gaming server use the most cpu cycles or disk usage?

This is assuming I can't install the same web-app or gaming server on my own machine and then monitor the cpu usage while I'm requesting different things from the server to figure out what uses the most cpu cycles.

- Are there any particularly resource heavy ASM instructions that are often called?
- When are they most frequently called? (What are the general ways which I can force the server to call these functions/instructions?)

Comment: This is a computer science question: "what are the most 'costly' instructions?" As for how to call them from a remote client? You don't. That's what technology stacks are for. DoS happens most often on other parts of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

In general, CPU power is not the first resource to be exhausted when doing DOS. And even when it is, it is not because some specific assembly instruction is CPU intensive, but rather because a task (e.g. "sort this list" or "solve this equation system") is CPU intensive.

So if you want to exhaust CPU power, your best bet it to find such a task. Aim for something where the CPU usage grows with the size of the input, and then provide an unexpectadly large input.

But if you just want to DOS a system, you are likely to be better off targeting something other than CPU usage - bandwith, number of simultaneous connections, internal memory, disk usage, etc.